# Is specifying the version when adding a pod necessary?

Tags: cocoapods

I often see many repository's cocoapods installation instructions that are similar to the following

> pod 'Something', '~> 1.1'

Is it necessary to add the version in the podfile? I've noticed it automatically grabs the latest version anyways from my experiences if the version is not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not necessary, you can use:

```
pod 'Something'
```

And the latest version will be installed on `pod update`.

---

You can also specify the major and minor version, so it will just update to the latest revision. (major.minor.revision)

```
pod 'Something, '~> 4.1'
```